# Java Methods call from Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, connection

[Main class from the package com.mw.tbx.ini on Eclipse IDE][1]

I built the classes and include them on a package "com.mw.tbx.ini" i already set the dynamic java path on Matlab but i could not upload my package. and call my method Compute() which i need to use on Matlab.

When i call the "Javaclasspath" and the "[M,X,J] = inmem" on matlab, it gives me :

> Blockquote

```
    DYNAMIC JAVA PATH

C:\Users\alaoui\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2010a\matrix.jar
```

> > [M,X,J] = inmem

M =

```
'opaque.char'
'workspacefunc'
'javaclasspath'
'strread'
'pathsep'
'strvcat'
'iscellstr'
```

X =

```
'dataread'
```

J =

```
'com.mathworks.widgets.spreadsheet.data.ValueSummaryFactory'
'com.mathworks.widgets.spreadsheet.data.ComplexScalarFactory'
'com.mathworks.widgets.spreadsheet.data.ComplexArrayFactory'
```

I guess it means that my matrix.jar is already uploaded!

Comment: Inmem is not supposed to return your class before you actually use  it. How do you try to use your code and what error do you get?

Comment: Is the jar compiled for the java version MATLAB uses? Use `ver` to get the right version.

Comment: Depending on what your java class does, it may need to be on the static path instead. See yair's extensive post about this: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/static-java-classpath-hacks

Comment: @ Daniel I got Java version in Matlab : 1.6.0 / And the jar file compiled with 1.8.0 .Thank you for your reply